# If $m>n>0$ and $\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n}$ = $\frac{1}{9}$, find all possible values for $(m, n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving

From a problem in a recent math competition. Was wondering if it was possible to logically solve for the answer instead of guessing and checking.

If $m>n>0$ and $\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n}$ = $\frac{1}{9}$, find all possible values for $(m, n)$

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Do you know [SFFT](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick)?

Comment: common denominator and cross multiplication gets me to $9(m+n) = mn$, don't know what to do from there.

Comment: the answers that were given after the completion of the contest were $(36, 12)$ and $(90, 10)$

Comment: Assuming you are looking for integers, rearrange $mn-9m-9n=0$ to $(m-9)(n-9)=81$ and think about pairs of factors of 81.

Comment: Readers should not have to guess whether you meant $m,n$ to be (positive) integers.  You give a Comment (about the solution "after the completion of the contest") that suggests so, but the body of your Question should give a complete statement of the problem you want help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{9}$ is equivalent to $$81=(m-9)(n-9)$$

The divisors of $81$ are $\pm1,\pm3,\pm9,\pm27,\pm81$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the relation as
$9m + 9n = mn$.

Solving, we see that the only solutions (say over the positive reals) are of the form $(9n/(n-9), n)$.

Clearly we must have $n > 9$. Additionally, the constraint $m > n$ implies $9/(n-9) > 1$. So $n < 18$.

Now you can just check $n\in \{10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17\}$,
to see when $9n/(n-9)$ is an integer.

The solutions are thus with $n \in \{10, 12\}$, and plugging into
$m = 9n/(n-9)$, the pairs are
$$
(90, 10), \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
(36, 12). 
$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume $m$ and $n$ are integers.

Since $\frac{1}{m}=\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{n}$ and $m,n>0$, we know that $n\ge 10$. Also, since $\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-9}{9n}=\frac{1}{m}$, we know that $m=\frac{9n}{n-9}$. So $m>n$ gives us $\frac{9n}{n-9}>n$ which simplifies to $0>n(n-18)$ and since $0<n$ this means $0>n-18$, so we now have $10 \le n < 18$.

Thus $n=10, 11, \dots, 17$ and plugging in these values to $\frac{9n}{n-9}$ should give you the corresponding $m$-values.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that $m$ and $n$ are integers: otherwise there would be an infinity of answers.

Clearly neither integer can be less than $10$, since that would make the other negative. We may write the equation as
$$(m-9)(n-9)=81.$$
Because $81=3^4$, it can factorize exactly three ways into two factors: $81=1\times81=3\times27=9\times9$. Adding $9$ to these factors gives the complete set of solutions:
$$(m,n)\in\{(90,10),(36,12)\},$$
which comprises the only two solutions remaining after applying the condition $m>n$.

Comment: One of your solutions doesn’t satisfy the stipulation $m>n$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks. I overlooked that condition.